# how to find a product inside my db using keyword from a link? (mongodb, express)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, express, search

I am trying to build a search bar with react, express and mongodb.

I used the following code from a tutorial inside my own frontend app and it loads all the products inside my db in a Json file, when i enter

> 127.0.0.1:5000/api/products/

also, it loads the information of a specific product, using the full title, when i enter

> 127.0.0.1:5000/api/products/gopro

i am usind this api for a specific product

```
  router.get("/:id", async (req, res)=> {
  const products = await Product.find({slug: req.params.id});
  if (products) {
    res.send(products);
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({message:"product not found"})
  } 
  });
```

and this api if i want to display all products

```
router.get('/',
expressAsyncHandler( async (req, res)=> {
    const name =  req.query.slug || "";
    const nameFilter= name ? { name: {$regex: name, $options: 'i'} } : {};
    const products = await Product.find({
      ...nameFilter,
    });
    res.send(products);
})
);
```

The second api should work if i enter just a searchword as well, but it does not.
if i enter

> 127.0.0.1:5000/api/product/logo

(i want to search for "logo printer"), i am just getting an empty array back instead of the information, that contains "logo" in the title.

i tried to change
**name = req.query.slug**
into
**name = req.query.name**
and
**name = req.query.title**
and **query** into **params**, but that doesent worked as well, but it worked in the tutorial.

Did i miss to do something, or is there another way to search using exactly this link?
I really stuck at this point.

Comment: try to console.log(req.query.slug), the data is correct ?

Comment: i tried it with "name", "title" and "slug". 
it was "undefined" every time

Comment: then you have to check the query you are sending from frontend